# Pandas: repetitive for loop with specific index

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    time                 event  
  2019-01-01 01:27:00   crossing down           
1 2019-01-01 01:36:00   crossing up         
2 2019-01-01 01:42:00   crossing down           
3 2019-01-01 01:55:00   crossing up     
4 2019-01-01 01:58:00   crossing down   
5 2019-01-01 01:59:00   crossing up         
6 2019-01-01 02:00:00   crossing down       
7 2019-01-01 02:17:00   crossing up
```

What I need to do is to compute the average time between a trend (crossing down to crossing up "uptrend", or crossing up to crossing down "downtrend"). What I would need is an array of all the uptrend so the time between `1 2019-01-01 01:36:00   crossing up` and `2019-01-01 01:27:00   crossing down`, plus the time between `3 2019-01-01 01:55:00   crossing up` and `2 2019-01-01 01:42:00   crossing down`, etc.... and an array of all the downtrend so the time between `1 2019-01-01 01:36:00   crossing up` and `2 2019-01-01 01:42:00   crossing down`, etc... What I tried so far:

```
for index,row in df_trend.iterrows():
    if df_trend.loc[0, 'event'] == 'crossing down':    
        up_trend_time = np.append(up_trend_time,(df_trend.loc[index+1, 'time'] - df_trend.loc[index, 'time']))

    elif df_trend.loc[0, 'event'] == 'crossing up':  
        down_trend_time = np.append(up_trend_time,(df_trend.loc[index+1, 'time'] - df_trend.loc[index, 'time']))
```

but it does not give me the expected output: an array `up_trend_time=[9,7,1,17]` and `down_trend_time=[6,3,1]`, any help? thanks!

Plus I have the following error with my current code:

```
'the label [1676] is not in the [index]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
up_trend_time = (df.groupby((df['event'] == 'crossing down').cumsum())['time'].diff()
                   .dropna().dt.total_seconds().floordiv(60).tolist())

down_trend_time = (df.groupby((df['event'] == 'crossing up').cumsum())['time'].diff()
                     .dropna().dt.total_seconds().floordiv(60).tolist())

up_trend_time
[9.0, 13.0, 1.0, 17.0]

down_trend_time
[6.0, 3.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time = np.array([])
up = np.array([])
down = np.array([])

for index in range(len(df_trend) -1):
    if df_trend.loc[0, 'event'] == 'crossing down':    
        time = np.append(time,(df_trend.loc[index+1, 'time'] - df_trend.loc[index, 'time']))

    elif df_trend.loc[0, 'event'] == 'crossing up':  
        time = np.append(time,(df_trend.loc[index+1, 'time'] - df_trend.loc[index, 'time']))


if df_trend.loc[0, 'event'] == 'crossing down': 
    up =  time[::2]
    down = time[1:][::2]
else: 
    up = time[1:][::2]
    down = time[::2]
```